# Adding and removing dynamically generated QLineEdit widgets based off of user input from a QComboBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I'm building an app to 'roll' multiple die of the same face, so if I need to roll 5  8 sided die I select 5 in the QComboBox under the label D8, then 5 QLineEdit widgets pop up with the values of the 5 'die rolls' displayed.

Currently I'm able to display the correct number of QLineEdit widgets after a number in the QComboBox is selected. The problem comes when I try to remove the die roll displays entirely or set the number of QLineEdit widgets to less than the first value set. Sometimes it works, never when I try to set the displays to 0, other times I'll throw a KeyError or RuntimeError.

```
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QLabel, QComboBox, QDialog, QApplication

class RollMultiDiePopup(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RollMultiDiePopup, self).__init__(parent)
        #self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Additional Dies to roll')
        self.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.comboDict = {"D4": 4, "D6": 6, "D8": 8, "D10": 10, "D12": 12, "D20": 20}
        self.comboLblDict = {"# of D4s": 0, "# of D6s": 0, "# of D8s": 0, "# of D10s": 0, "# of D12s": 0, "# of D20s": 0}
        self.layoutGrid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.layoutGrid.setSpacing(10)
        self.gridRow = 0
        self.gridCol = 0
        self.comboLbl = {}
        self.comboBoxes = {}
        self.addnlInputs = {}
        self.generatecombolabels()
        self.generatecomboboxes()
        self.generaterollbuttons()
        self.setLayout(self.layoutGrid)
        self.adjustSize()

    def generatecombolabels(self):
        self.gridCol = 0
        for key, val in self.comboLblDict.items():
            self.gridCol = self.gridCol + 1
            self.comboLbl[key] = QLabel(key, self)
            self.layoutGrid.addWidget(self.comboLbl[key], 0, self.gridCol)

    def generatecomboboxes(self):
        self.gridCol = 0
        for key, val in self.comboDict.items():
            self.gridCol = self.gridCol + 1
            self.comboBoxes[key] = QComboBox(self)
            self.comboBoxes[key].addItems([str(x) for x in range(21)])
            #self.comboBoxes[key].activated.connect(self.adddisplays)
            self.layoutGrid.addWidget(self.comboBoxes[key], 1, self.gridCol)

    def generaterollbuttons(self):
        self.gridCol = 0
        for key, val in self.comboDict.items():
            self.gridCol = self.gridCol + 1
            buttons = QPushButton("Roll " + key + "s", self)
            buttons.setToolTip("Roll D" + str(self.comboDict[key]) + " (1 - " + str(self.comboDict[key]) + ")")
            #buttons.clicked.connect(partial(self.rolldie, val))
            buttons.clicked.connect(self.adddisplays)
            self.layoutGrid.addWidget(buttons, 2, self.gridCol)

    def rolldie(self):
        pass

    def adddisplays(self):
        d4s = int(self.comboBoxes["D4"].currentText())
        d6s = int(self.comboBoxes["D6"].currentText())
        d8s = int(self.comboBoxes["D8"].currentText())
        d10s = int(self.comboBoxes["D10"].currentText())
        d12s = int(self.comboBoxes["D12"].currentText())
        d20s = int(self.comboBoxes["D20"].currentText())
        dies = {1: d4s, 2: d6s, 3: d8s, 4: d10s, 5: d12s, 6: d20s}
        #if d4s == 0 or d6s == 0 or d8s == 0 or d10s == 0 or d12s == 0 or d20s == 0:
        self.removeaddeddisplays()
        if d4s > 0 or d6s > 0 or d8s > 0 or d10s > 0 or d12s > 0 or d20s > 0:
            for keys, vals in dies.items():
                self.gridRow = 3
                for i in range(vals):
                    self.gridRow += 1
                    self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)] = QLineEdit(self)
                    self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)].setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
                    self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)].setText("")
                    self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)].setPlaceholderText("Die Roll #" + str(i + 1))
                    self.layoutGrid.addWidget(self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)], self.gridRow, keys)

    def removeaddeddisplays(self):
        try:
            for i in range(3, 21):
                self.layoutGrid.removeWidget(self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)])
                self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)].deleteLater()
                self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)] = None
                self.adjustSize()
        except KeyError:
            print("1")
        except RuntimeError:
            print("2")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    w = RollMultiDiePopup()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

This is the code to initially generate the QComboBoxes and populate the list of #s.

```
self.gridCol = 0
for key, val in self.comboDict.items():
    self.gridCol = self.gridCol + 1
    self.comboBoxes[key] = QComboBox(self)
    self.comboBoxes[key].addItems([str(x) for x in range(21)])
    #self.comboBoxes[key].activated.connect(self.adddisplays)
    self.layoutGrid.addWidget(self.comboBoxes[key], 1, self.gridCol)
```

This is the code that adds the displays when the button that corresponds with the D# label/Combo box

```
d4s = int(self.comboBoxes["D4"].currentText())
d6s = int(self.comboBoxes["D6"].currentText())
d8s = int(self.comboBoxes["D8"].currentText())
d10s = int(self.comboBoxes["D10"].currentText())
d12s = int(self.comboBoxes["D12"].currentText())
d20s = int(self.comboBoxes["D20"].currentText())
dies = {1: d4s, 2: d6s, 3: d8s, 4: d10s, 5: d12s, 6: d20s}
#if d4s == 0 or d6s == 0 or d8s == 0 or d10s == 0 or d12s == 0 or d20s == 0:
self.removeaddeddisplays()
if d4s > 0 or d6s > 0 or d8s > 0 or d10s > 0 or d12s > 0 or d20s > 0:
    for keys, vals in dies.items():
        self.gridRow = 3
        for i in range(vals):
            self.gridRow += 1
            self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)] = QLineEdit(self)
            self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)].setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
            self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)].setText("")
            self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)].setPlaceholderText("Die Roll #" + str(i + 1))
            self.layoutGrid.addWidget(self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)], self.gridRow, keys)
```

Here's the removeaddeddisplays function

```
try:
    for i in range(3, 21):
        self.layoutGrid.removeWidget(self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)])
        self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)].deleteLater()
        self.addnlInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)] = None
        self.adjustSize()
except KeyError:
     print("1")
except RuntimeError:
     print("2")
```

I've tried several different ways to remove the widgets and wound up with different results, only removing every other display, everything, every third..etc. This has been the most consistent way so far that I've found.

I'm using python 3 and pyside 2, I'll worry about handling the die rolls after I get the displays working properly.

Comment: One question, what is the difference between D4 and D8 ?, does the number 4 indicate that the QComboBox should take values from 1 to 4 and 8 indicates that its corresponding QComboBox should take values from 1 to 8?

Comment: D4 would be the number of 4 sided die to roll, D8 is the number of 8 sided die to roll. The QComboBox will tell the rolldie function to roll X number of 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 and 20 sided dies. Then display the results of the rolls in the QLineEdits that are being generated. I'm only wanting to generate the number of QLineEdits needed for the number of die rolled. I can do that fine, the problem is when I'm removing the inputs to roll a lesser number of die.

https://i.imgur.com/nU0sxjw.png - screenshot of gui without displays
https://i.imgur.com/AyimE7G.png - screenshot of gui with displays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove a widget from a layout you just have to use deleteLater but that does not mean that the references will be deleted if they are stored in a list. In my strategy I eliminate all the QLineEdits with deleteLater, I reset the list that stored it and I create the new QLineEdits.

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class RollMultiDiePopup(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RollMultiDiePopup, self).__init__(parent)

        self._data = {
            "D4": 4, 
            "D6": 6, 
            "D8": 8, 
            "D10": 10, 
            "D12": 12, 
            "D20": 20
        }

        self._lineedits = [[] for _ in self._data]
        self._comboboxes = []

        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.create_labels()
        self.create_comboboxes()
        self.create_buttons()

    def create_labels(self):
        row = 0
        grid_layout = self.layout()
        for i, k in enumerate(self._data.keys()):
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel("# of {}s".format(k))
            grid_layout.addWidget(label, row, i)

    def create_comboboxes(self):
        row = 1
        grid_layout = self.layout()
        for i in range(len(self._data)):
            combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
            combo.addItems([str(j) for j in range(21)])
            self._comboboxes.append(combo)
            grid_layout.addWidget(combo, row, i)

    def create_buttons(self):
        row = 2
        grid_layout = self.layout()
        for i, (k, v) in enumerate(self._data.items()):
            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Roll {}s".format(k))
            button.setToolTip("Roll {}(1 - {})".format(k, v))
            button.clicked.connect(self.update_lineedits)
            grid_layout.addWidget(button, row, i)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def update_lineedits(self):
        row = 3
        grid_layout = self.layout()
        for r in self._lineedits:
            for le in r:
                le.deleteLater()
        self._lineedits = [[] for _ in self._data]
        for i, (les,combo) in enumerate(zip(self._lineedits, self._comboboxes)):
            v = int(combo.currentText())
            for j in range(v):
                le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
                le.setPlaceholderText("Die Roll #{}".format(j+1))
                grid_layout.addWidget(le, row+j, i)
                les.append(le)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.adjust_size)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def adjust_size(self):
        animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"size", self)
        animation.setStartValue(self.size())
        animation.setEndValue(self.minimumSizeHint())
        animation.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = RollMultiDiePopup()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This works great! However when you set them all back to 0 this happens: https://i.imgur.com/tGqDkUs.png

I've tried `self.adjustSize()` about everywhere in the `update_lineedits` function and it still looks that way.

Comment: If i wanted to change the text of one of the qlineedits that are generated using your method, how exactly would I do that? I'm unable to figure out how to do a setText on any single qlineedit, without it being all of them.

Comment: use `self._lineedits[index_i][index_j].setText(">>>>>")`